# Remove @include depending on the route

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I have a menu partial, that includes a input search bar. But i don't want the search bar to be visibel on all pages, only for two specific uri´s. Is there a way to remove that include in blade?

Currently it looks like this:

```
<a href="{{ route('all') }}">all</a>
<a href="{{ route('nes') }}">nes</a>
<a href="{{ route('snes') }}">snes</a>
@include('partials._search')
```

I was thinking something like

```
<a href="{{ route('all') }}">all</a>
<a href="{{ route('nes') }}">nes</a>
<a href="{{ route('snes') }}">snes</a>
@if($url)
    @include('partials._search')
@endif
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `is()` method:

```
@if (request()->is($url))
    @include('partials._search')
@endif
```

Or if you know route name:

```
@if (request()->route()->getName() === $routeName)
    @include('partials._search')
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve URL from the blade template, use `{{ Request::url() }}`.
This will output something like **http://example.dev/articles**

To retrieve path, use `{{ Request::path() }}`
Using the above example, this will output **articles**.