# Laravel hide code if requested Path was

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Theres any Solution to hide an Code in Laravel for one Page?

With this i can display only one requested page ,Example:

```
 @if (Request::path() == 'message/send')
 @endif
```

Theres an opposite to hide an code for an path?

I have an URL also with after `send` an Username:

```
message/send/username
```

I have try:  `@if (Request::path() == 'message/send/')` and  `@if (Request::path() == 'message/send/{{$username}}')` but dont work.

Thanks

Comment: Why dont you simply use a flag in your controller?

Comment: You have an Single Page Application that you are using the backend in Laravel and you need that you backend could handle only 'message/send' all others you want that can be proccesed by you SPA, that's right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`request()->is()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41852545/1227923) for this:

```
@if (request()->is('message/send*'))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use segment method in laravel

```
    @php $member = Request::segment(1);@endphp
       @if($member =='member') 
       <style type="text/css"> .test{color: #1a393a !important;</style>
       @endif
    @endif
```

Here my first segment is member

Answer (score 0):

The controller is the proper place to handle request specifics.  However, if you still wish to do this in your blade view:

```
@if (Request::path() == 'message/send/' . $username)
```

You do not use template syntax `{{ }}` inside expressions.  When the blade template is compiled, `@if (expr)` is converted to `<?php if (expr): ?>`, so standard PHP applies within the expression.

Comment: Then i get the error: "Undefined variable: username".  why, i use it?

Comment: Then you don't have $username registered with the view....  I'm just going based on your code.

Answer (score 0):

Route path comparison doesn't work that way. For example:
`message/send/jwz104` will never be equal to `message/send/{{$username}}`

You could compare the route name:

```
@if(\Request::route()->getName() == 'message.send')
@endif
```

This also isn't a nice solution. You should handle this in your controller or by view composers.

Answer (score 0):

with core `php`-

```
@if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "message/send") !== false)

@endif
```