# Laravel sidebar hide on custom page

Tags: php, laravel, hide

I working with laravel, searched on internet but nothing found. I got simple sidebar widget: `@widget('Partners::Partners')`
How can i hide on custom page? Like example: /forums? Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`request()->is()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41852545/1227923):

```
@if (!request()->is('forum*'))
    @widget('Partners::Partners')
@endif
```